# GuardHelpers not working with customGuard

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I have made the following custom guard:

```
<?php
namespace App\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class LicenseGuard implements Guard
{
    use GuardHelpers;

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(LicenseUserProvider $provider, Request $request)
    {
        $this->provider = $provider;
        $this->request  = $request;
    }

    public function user ()
    {
        // If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
        // return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
        // every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
        if (!is_null($this->user))
            return $this->user;

        $user       = null;
        $licenseKey = $this->request->json('license_key');

        if (!empty($licenseKey)) {
            $user = $this->provider->retrieveByLicense($licenseKey);
        }

        return $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function validate (Array $credentials = [])
    {
       /* Validate code */
    }
}
?>
```

In my middleware i have defined the following:

```
<?php
if($this->auth->guard($guard)->quest())
    return response('You have entered an unknown license key', 401);
```

The error that i am getting is:
***Fatal error: Call to undefined method App\Auth\LicenseGuard::quest()***

I am using the default GuardHelper trait which has the "quest" method, i just can't find out why this is happening.

I am using PHP7 and Lumen 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing there my friend, but I assume `quest` "isn't the droids you are looking for".

Comment: walk it off champ :)